# How to expose ListeningExecuterService as Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, guava

Was wondering if there is a way to expose ListeningExecuterService as Spring Singleton bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research found a way

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutorService() {
    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
        .setNameFormat(" Listening Executor Service [%d]").build();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(
            SOMECONSTANT.TASK_EXECUTOR_THREADS, threadFactory);
    return MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService);
}
```

Here's the XML Config

```
 <!-- ThreadPool for executing   functions asynchronously -->
       <bean id="functionThreadPool" class="com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors" factory-method="listeningDecorator">
          <constructor-arg>
                 <bean class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newCachedThreadPool"/>                     
          </constructor-arg>
     </bean>
```